# syntax error with mysqldbcompare command

Tags: mysql

mysql -V is 5.5.54 for debian (Jessie).

I'm at the mysql command prompt trying to run this command:

```
mysqldbcompare --server1=root@localhost calendar_dup:calendar --run-all-tests
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL sytax; check manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntx to use near 'mysqldbcompare --server1=root@127.0.0.1 calendar_dup:calendar --run-all-tests' at line 1

Comment: ...to your MySQL server version for the right syntx to use near 'mysqldbcompare --server1=root@127.0.0.1 calendar_dup:calendar --run-all-tests' at line 1

Comment: `mysqldbcompare` can't compare `--server1` to nothing... where's your `--server2` option?

Comment: according to docs, it's not needed: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqldbcompare.html

Comment: and even with --server2 i get same error

Answer (score 0):

Needed to install via apt-get: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mysql-utilities

Also, should be run from shell command line, not mysql command line.